# How to run automated tests from TFS 2013 UI?

Tags: tfs, automated-tests

Let's say there are some unit tests that initiate a Selenium process and test a website's functionality. The unit tests are linked to test cases and can be initiated from the Test Manager. There are test agents running on several machines.

Is it possible to run an automated test from the TFS2013 Test UI? When I click Run it says it's an automated test and can't be run. Is it possible to change TFS configuration to make it run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant start an automated test execution run from the web ui, yet.

http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

You can however use an automated release triggered from a build to do it. And you can start a build in the UI...

Comment: I thought so, but didn't want to believe it. And I didn't see anything regarding this in the TFS roadmap either: http://www.visualstudio.com/news/release-archive-vso